# wordpress redirect not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-url

```
     
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
 
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('societies/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=societies&sid=$matches[1]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}
 
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');


function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "page_id";    // represents the name of the variable as shown in the URL
    return $aVars;
}
 
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

So I'm attempting to use a custom get variable on redirect. Currently I have a redirect that takes you to a section of my site: zzz.net/dashboard?page_id=2278, for example but I'm getting a 404 page could not be displayed, so I added this code. Main issue is I really don't have the best idea of what I'm doing.

The reason I want to have ?page_id=2278, etc. on redirect is so I can know where the user just came from before they got to the dashboard page.

Advise and direction might be more helpful then just answers. Either way thank you for taking a moment to look at it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a Wordpress Page that has an ID of 2278?

Comment: I'm using advanced custom fields, to specify particular parts of a form. Those forms are given a reference page_id=2278, etc. This is to know what form/petition someone just filled out. That way I can serve them customized information in their "dashboard."

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The page_id parameter is a recognized Wordpress GET variable. If you don't have a Wordpress page that has an id of 2278, then I'm not entirely surprised that you're getting a 404.

Comment: Well, that I'm not so proud of, we are using a template page id reference from an API. Essentially the way we are keeping track of this API that is a backend where we submit these forms, is via the page_id=####. It's our identification back to the original template which was generated on the API side. All I need to do is get zzz.net/dashboard?page_id=777 to be the same as doing zzz.net/dashboard the trailing page_id=777 is essentially just a marker to keep track.

Comment: we are uploading the template and pulling out the form fields, and the page_id is the reference back to the original template page on the API side. (which is working).

Comment: I really think it's simpler than that, correct? Can't I just do a rewrite to rules for that page, which states if I have something like zzz.net/dashboard?page_id=2238 it treats it just like zzz.net/dashboard :

Comment: Which leads me back to my original question: Do you have a Wordpress Page with an ID of 2278? If you answer no, then your problem is your variable naming conventions is confusing Wordpress. If yes, then it's something else.

Comment: http://zzz.net/?page_id=2786 is not a page and my permalink settings are for day and name. i don't know if that effects things.

Comment: Then you're missing my point: YOU CAN'T USE A VARIABLE NAMED 'page_id'. It confuses Wordpress, because it's trying to search for a registered Wordpress Page with an ID of 2786. If that page doesn't exist, of COURSE it will 404 on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GET variable named 'page_id' is utilized by the Wordpress core when querying any Page Objects.

Conversely, if you were to change the query to 'p=2786', then Wordpress would try and search for a Post with an ID of 2786.

By having that variable in your URL, Wordpress is getting confused and is trying to return a Page that has an ID of what is defined by your GET request. In order to prevent naming conflicts like these, it's always best to add a prefix to any named variables that are accessible within Global scope.

Change the name of your GET variable to something else (ie: WJ_page_id) to ensure you aren't conflicting with any main Wordpress variables.

Comment: thank you that worked like a charm, I appreciate your patience.

Comment: No trouble. This is a pretty easy thing to overlook, so please mark this as answered in case other users might have the same question you did.